# I use do while in the code and I get error

Tags: java

I want write a program that shows menu and asks the user to select from two choices
 a) Find odd numbers  : The program asks the user to enter integer number x, then prints the odd integers from x to 1
b) Find even numbers: The program asks the user to enter integer number x, then prints the even integers from x to 2.
- Your code should recognize the invalid characters and display "invalid choice!!" message.
- The program should display the message “Do you want to continue ? y or n “ after each calculation. The user will enter ‘y’ to continue, otherwise the user will enter 'n'. I wrote my code like this

```
import java.util.*;

public class choices{
    //main method
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String op;
        int num;

        String op2;
        String odd="";
        String even="";
        int count=0;

        do{
            System.out.println("a) Find odd numbers");
            System.out.println("b) Find even numbers");
            System.out.print("choose an option [ a, b]: ");
            op=input.next();
            if (op.equals('a'))
                System.out.print("Enter Integer number : ");
            num=input.nextInt();

            for(int i=num ; i >=num-i ;i--){
                if(num%2!=0)
                    odd=odd+""+i;
                System.out.print("odd numbers are : "+odd );
            }

            if (op.equals('b')){
                for(int i=num ; i >=num-i ;i--){
                    if(num%2==0)
                        even=even+""+i;      
                    System.out.print("even numbers are : "+even );
                }
            }
            else
                System.out.println("invalid choice");

            System.out.print("Do you want to continue (y or n)?");
            op2=input.next();  


            if(op2.equals('n')) 
                System.out.println("Bye");
        }

        while(!op2.equals('n'));
        count++;



    }
}
```

but the problem is : it stop after > choose an option [ a, b]: b

```
a) Find odd numbers
b) Find even numbers
choose an option [ a, b]: b
d
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
       at choices.main(choices.java:30)
```

Comment: dugger or System.out.println statements.

Comment: whats the "d" after you input b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues.

First, you need to wrap the code of your if statements in braces. This is what I assume you want:

```
if (op.equals('a'))
{
    System.out.print("Enter Integer number : ");
    num=input.nextInt();

    for(int i=num ; i >=num-i ;i--)
    {
        if(num%2!=0)
            odd=odd+""+i;
        System.out.print("odd numbers are : "+odd );
    }
}
```

Secondly, `'a'` is a character, so your if condition never passes. You need to do `op.equals("a")`. The issue is that it's skipping over your second prompt, because the if statement fails, then you are feeding it `"d"` for `input.nextInt()` for whatever reason, and you are getting a type error.

Comment: and third, OP probably don't even want if (op.equals('a')) there anyway as he needs a seed integer in both cases a and b. The whole if seems out-of-place.

Comment: he is getting the seed integer from his next statement, the `num=input.nextInt();`. The baffling part is that OP typed the letter `d` for this prompt, which threw a type error.

Comment: yes, but the message to enter integer number is only printed if op is 'a', which makes no sense. OP probably typed the letter d for this prompt because the message to type a digit was never printed due to unneeded if.

Comment: I am aware, that's pretty much what I said in the bottom section of answer. The a/b distinction is needed because the program sums either even or odd numbers depending on which one is typed in.

Comment: if you're aware that seed integer is needed for both a and b, why are you suggesting OP should use braces in a way the integer is only read if op equals a?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.print("choose an option [ a, b]: ");
op=input.next();
if (op.equals('a'))
System.out.print("Enter Integer number : ");
num=input.nextInt();
```

notice the scope of your if here. It's probably wrong. You're calling nextInt() every time.

Answer (score 0):

after this line `op=input.next();` (it can be a or b) next is this `num=input.nextInt();` and you can't choose `d`, because it isn't an Int. try to catch exception:

```
boolean stopFlag = false;

do {
...
System.out.print("choose an option [ a, b]: ");
op=input.next();
if (op.equals('a')) { // i think `{` must be here
    System.out.print("Enter Integer number : ");
    try {
       num=input.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
       // this wasn't an int 
       System.out.println("You entered not a correct number.");
       System.out.println("Bye");
       stopFlag = true;
    }
    ///
    for(int i=num ; i >=num-i ;i--){
        if(num%2!=0)
            odd=odd+""+i;
        System.out.print("odd numbers are : "+odd );
    }
} // and `}` here
...
// make the same with `b`
...
while(!stopFlag);
```